# How do view more than 999 files in directory via the Google Colab file browser?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a Colab Notebook running for deep-learning image training. Every 100 iterations of the model, it writes a preview jpg showing current progress to a directory. However, I now have more than 999 jpgs in that directory. When browsing the directory with the Colab file viewer, only the first 999 files are shown. After that a triple elipses (...) is shown, but clicking it doesn't seem to have any functionality.

Is there any way to view files beyond 999 in the Colab viewer itself?

Thanks!